# How to get the background color code of an element in hex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hex, background-color

How do I get the background color code of an element?

```js
console.log($(".div").css("background-color"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div" style="background-color: #f5b405"></div>
```

**What I want**

```
#f5b405
```

Comment: What are you wanting to do with the value?

Comment: I want to animate the background colour - `$(this).animate({ backgroundColor: '#f5b405' }, 'fast');`

Comment: But I just found out that I can use the rgb code to animate the background colour too! lol

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Check example link below and click on the div to get the color value in hex.

```js
var color = '';
$('div').click(function() {
  var x = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
  hexc(x);
  console.log(color);
})

function hexc(colorval) {
  var parts = colorval.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
  delete(parts[0]);
  for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
    parts[i] = parseInt(parts[i]).toString(16);
    if (parts[i].length == 1) parts[i] = '0' + parts[i];
  }
  color = '#' + parts.join('');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='div' style='background-color: #f5b405'>Click me!</div>
```

**Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/DCaQb/**

Comment: Sometimes `$(this).css('backgroundColor')` returns `rgba(n, n, n, n)`.

Comment: Played around a bit with your function to automatize design modernization and such... Example usage scenario http://jsfiddle.net/DCaQb/625/ - not perfect but maybe it helps somebody so I link it here for reference

Comment: Thanks for this code example. Might want to just rewrite that hexc function as a real function that returns the string though instead of setting a global variable.

Answer (score 11):

There's a bit of a hack for this, since the HTML5 canvas is required to parse color values when certain properties like `strokeStyle` and `fillStyle` are set:

```
var ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(64, 128, 192)';
var hexColor = ctx.strokeStyle;
```

Comment: i believe this one is the best approach for new html5 browsers :)

Answer (score 9):

```
function getBackgroundColor($dom) {
    var bgColor = "";
    while ($dom[0].tagName.toLowerCase() != "html") {
      bgColor = $dom.css("background-color");
      if (bgColor != "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)" && bgColor != "transparent") {
        break;
      }
      $dom = $dom.parent();
    }
    return bgColor;
  }
```

working properly under Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 5):

You have the color you just need to convert it into the format you want.

Here's a script that should do the trick: http://www.phpied.com/rgb-color-parser-in-javascript/

Answer (score 5):

In fact, if there is no definition of `background-color` under some element, Chrome will output its `background-color` as `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)`, while Firefox outputs is `transparent`.

Answer (score 4):

My beautiful non-standard solution

**HTML**

```
<div style="background-color:#f5b405"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(this).attr("style").replace("background-color:", "");
```

**Result**

```
#f5b405
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding on @Newred solution.
If your style has more than just the `background-color` you can use this:

```
$(this).attr('style').split(';').filter(item => item.startsWith('background-color'))[0].split(":")[1]
```

Comment: I like this way

Answer (score 1):

This Solution utilizes part of what @Newred and @Radu Diță said.  But will work in less standard cases.

```
 $(this).attr('style').split(';').filter(item => item.startsWith('background-color'))[0].split(":")[1].replace(/\s/g, '');
```

The issue both of them have is that neither check for a space between background-color:  and the color.

All of these will match with the above code.

```
 background-color: #ffffff
 background-color:      #fffff;
 background-color:#fffff;
```