# Hiding any elements with certain style

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm trying to write a script to hide all elements with a certain style.

I want to do something like this:

```
var hide = document.getElementByStyle("border: 3px ridge #333333").style.display="none";
```

Comment: Try this solution, seems to be close enough.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767701/javascript-css-get-element-by-style-attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function editStyles(el) {
    if(el.getAttribute('style') == 'border: 3px ridge #333333')el.style.display='none';

    if(el.childNodes.length > 0) {
        for(var child in el.childNodes) {
            if(el.childNodes[child].nodeType == 1)
                editStyles(el.childNodes[child]);
        }
    }
}

editStyles(document.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put that css into a css.class, and use `getElementsByClassName()`. Then just hide elements with that class when they occurs...