# Testing for correct cursor type when hovering over elements in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests, nunit

I need to write an automated test with Selenium and C# which determines if the hovering the cursor over an element in a web application changes it to a pointer or not. For example, the cursor should change to a pointer when it hovers over the Home link at the top of the page. Is this possible using this framework?

Comment: Cursor changing to a pointer usually occurs when a link is hovered over, so it would probably be better to test for the presence / absence of a link, rather than checking the pointer itself. Another user below mentioned checking `style` attributes for `cursor:` and `pointer:` on an element -- you can use `WebElement.GetAttribute("style")` to check these attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Selenium is the precise tool for the job. I did a quick look and came across another page on stack overflow, [Javascript, CSS: Get element by style attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767701/javascript-css-get-element-by-style-attribute) that talks about finding elements by the style attributes.

You would be looking for the style attribute on objects: cursor: pointer;

Hope this helps.