# Embed CSS attribute in HTML

Tags: css, html, less

I have the color theme of a website I'm working on change on refresh and would like to display the css background color attribute in my HTML. Is that possible?

i.e.

```
<footer>The color of the moment is <insert the background color attribute>. Refresh for a makeover</footer>
```

would display something like

"The color of the moment is #DB0C0C. Refresh for a makeover"

Since the hex color changes based on the style sheet loaded, I don't want to hardcode it. If I had a ruby variable @color which = #ff0000 and wanted to display it in html I could do something like

```
<%= @color%>
```

I'm wondering if there is any way to do something similar to access a CSS attribute.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just write it in?

Comment: Then based on your edit, what you need is javascript.   There is no pure css/html way to get that value otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need jQuery for this.. you can use just vanilla javascript with [`.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle):

```
<span id='color-map'></span>

var element = document.getElementById("id-goes-here");
var style = window.getComputedStyle(element);

document.getElementById('color-map').innerHTML = style.backgroundColor;
```

However, it would appear that this does not give the color as a hex, but rather an 'rpg(x, y, z)' string.  To get the hex from that, you can parse it using regex and return the result:

```
function rgbsToHex(str) {
    var hex = "#";
    var matches = str.match(/rgb\((\d+),\s(\d+),\s(\d+)\)/);
    hex += Number(matches[1]).toString(16);
    hex += Number(matches[2]).toString(16);
    hex += Number(matches[3]).toString(16);
    return hex;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DbYz6/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .css() function in jQuery.

```
$('footer').find('span').text($('.bg').css('background-color'));
```

This will give you the color in rgb, if you would like to show it in HEX then check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999209/jquery-how-to-get-the-background-color-code-of-an-element) for more info.