# how to get the back ground color value from the css file using java script file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I have  jquery.corner.js file and  custom.css file,

For rounded corners i have used  jquery.corner.js  file, for rounded corners it is applying default color white(from jquery.corner.js). when i change the background color white to blue,the rounded corneres is displaying white. Now my requirement is when ever i change the background color to some other color, i have to get that some other color code into my  jquery.corner.js how to achieve it?

here is the code:

Custom.css

```
body {
    background: #FFFFFF;

}
```

in  jquery.corner.js file

`strip.style.borderColor = '#FFFFFF'` 
(i am manually adding color code, i dont want to add it manually) now in jquery.corner.js file  color code #FFFFFF has to get from custom.css file. how to achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999209/jquery-how-to-get-the-background-color-code-of-an-element

Comment: whenever you are changing the colour in that css file, simultaneously change the colour in that JS file by using notepad or any text editor. --- Seriously the question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely the `borderColor` already is set at load time. Check `console.log` to see what's already there.

```
 console.log(strip.style.borderColor);
```

If not, then you might need to apply a class to `strip` to apply the CSS.