# How to get a style value of an element - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, if-statement

how to get the the value of background-color property

```
if ($(this).css('background-color') == 'InfoBackground') 
{
     // it doesn't enter here
}
```

Comment: background-color expects a color code. You maybe want to check for the class: `$(this).hasClass('InfoBackground')`.

Comment: _Note that the computed style of an element may not be the same as the value specified for that element in a style sheet. For example, computed styles of dimensions are almost always pixels, but they can be specified as em, ex, px or % in a style sheet. Different browsers may return CSS color values that are logically but not textually equal, e.g., #FFF, #ffffff, and rgb(255,255,255)._

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999209/how-to-get-the-background-color-code-of-an-element

Comment: First: background-color should be a color. Second: Whats the code above?

Comment: Perhaps, InfoBackground is a variable? Then, use it without quote.

Comment: @Bernd InfoBackground is a right color name and the code is clear !

Comment: @Bernd: `InfoBackground` is a [CSS 2 System Color](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#css2-system).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

background color outputs are `rgb()` in jQuery as far as I know, so I don't think if there's a convenient way of comparing it!

take a look at [**THIS**](http://jsfiddle.net/7zv6ua21/1/) example,

```
alert($('#color').css('background-color'));
if($('#color').css('background-color')=='red'){
    alert('first if');
}
```

it will not enter the first if because `$('#color').css('background-color')` equals `rgb(255,0,0)` and it doesn't match `red` so it wont get inside the if condition.

what you can do, is to give the desired DOM a class, and check if the element has the class, like this:

```
if($('#color').hasClass('red')){
    alert('second if');
}
```

which will fire the alert inside of it.

Comment: I understood , but what about this ?
 if ($(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(251,252,197)') 
{
  // it should enter now , right ?
}

Comment: it will not, because you need to put a space after each semi-column like this `if ($(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(251, 252, 197)') { }`, now it will enter, but as I said above, it is not convenient, which means it's not a good idea to do it, because the output may differ in different browsers, the best and most common way is to use a class which I mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to check against the RGB value of whatever `InfoBackground` is.

Notice the following returns **`rgb(251, 252, 197)`**

```js
if ($("#myElement").css('background-color') == 'rgb(251, 252, 197)') {
     alert('hello');
}
```

```css
#myElement { background-color: InfoBackground; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myElement">Hi</div>
```

---

*However*, this seems like kind of a fickle approach.  Different browsers might behave differently or implement `InfoBackground` differently.  It would be better to assign a class, property, or data-attribute and then use that to dictate the color.

Comment: Mystery Downvoter?  Any reasons?

Comment: you are right , you mentioned the error but did't write the solution