# jQuery get green background of div in plain text (get "green", not "rgb(0,128,0)", not "#0f0")

Tags: javascript, jquery, background

I have a `div` with a `background-color` of `green`. In `HTML` and `JavaScript`:

```
<div id="rectangle" style="background-color:green;width:200px;height:100px"></div>

var div = document.getElementById("rectangle")
console.log(div.style.backgroundColor)
```

Console logs `green`.

I tried doing the same thing in jQuery. However I got:

```
var $div = $('#rectangle').css("backgroundColor"); 
console.log($div)
```

Console logs `rgb(0, 128, 0)`

Is there a way in `jQuery` to return the actual color of the text `green`. Alternatively is there an easy way to convert `rgb(0, 128, 0)` to `green`?

I am trying to GET the color, not set the color.

Comment: @Xufox wont it return rgb then ?

Comment: @Xufox I believe he's trying to indicate equality/result, not setting in those code snippets.

Comment: I dont want HEX value I want TEXT value

Comment: var jsSquare = document.getElementById('square').style.backgroundColor; console.log(jsSquare);
------> logs green :)

Comment: This could be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999209/how-to-get-the-background-color-code-of-an-element

Comment: that is returning a hex, I simply want it to return the actual name of the color in plain english "green". My question is different

Comment: You'd need to create a mapping between the `rgb` values and color names. Not difficult, but quite time consuming. I expect there are one or two sites on the internet that have that mapping though.

Comment: if you are setting color with jquery then get should also be using jquery only . and if you are setting color with javascript then get should also be using javascript only

Comment: Getting a css value via `.css()` uses the [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) function, which returns the browser's interpretation of the CSS which is applied to that element at that point. That's why the value differs from that provided by `style.backgroundColor`, which is what was originally set.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tiny color library here https://github.com/Olical/color
You can use it to convert the color in rgb string format into an array and than to it's name like this:

```js
console.info(color.toName(color.toArray("rgb(0, 128, 0)")))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/olical-color@1.0.1/src/color.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use jQuery's [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function with a single argument, it gets the currently applied (i.e., after stylesheets, inline styles, etc. are applied) style property matching the passed argument via the [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) function call.

Thus, when you call that function, you get the browser's internal representation of the CSS value originally set. Let's show that with an example, but using JavaScript against the DOM/CSSOM:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  var kermit = document.getElementById('kermit');
  console.log('style: ', kermit.style.backgroundColor);
  console.log('computed: ', window.getComputedStyle(kermit).backgroundColor);
};
```

```html
<div id="kermit" style="background-color: green; color: #fff">It ain't easy</div>
```

Depending on your browser, it should show `green` as the first log entry and `rgb(0, 128, 0)` for the second. I say "depending on your browser" because, as is explained in jQuery's css documentation:

> Different browsers may return CSS color values that are logically but not textually equal, e.g., #FFF, #ffffff, and rgb(255,255,255).

The easiest way to get what you want is ... well, beyond using a library as indicated by xxxmatko ... to create a mapping between the color values retrieved via `getComputedStyle` and the names. Note that this wouldn't tell you if the author of the stylesheet or whatever originally specified the color name, or some other value that happens to have the same RGB values.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  var colorMap = {
    'rgb(0, 128, 0)': 'green'
  };
  var kermit = document.getElementById('kermit');
  var computed = window.getComputedStyle(kermit).backgroundColor;
  console.log('color name: ', colorMap[computed]);
};
```

```html
<div id="kermit" style="background-color: green; color: #fff">It ain't easy</div>
```

Creating that map for the rest of the named colors (and the different corresponding color formats) is left as an exercise for the reader.