# Why is jQuery css.(backgroundColor) returning rgba(0,0,0,0)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create an each loop that will look at each div in a series and append that div's background color to it as text. It is working correctly for the first item, but returning rgba(0,0,0,0) for each subsequent element. The jquery in question is below, and the example codepen is: http://codepen.io/cvasquez/pen/RomWQw

```
$('.color-block').each(function(){
  var colorRgb = $(this).css('background-color');
  $(this).append('</br>' + colorRgb);
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999209/how-to-get-the-background-color-code-of-an-element

Comment: @ThomasJuranek That link shows how to get the color in Hex. The OP wants it as RGB().

Comment: Its because you are applying the class and then trying to get the value too quickly. The DOM needs to update to the new styles, which doesn't happen because you try to get the values right after setting the class. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JbqKNm

Answer (score -1):

try, this:

```
setTimeout(function($this){
  var colorRgb = $this.css('backgroundColor');
  $this.append('</br>' + colorRgb);
}, 100, $this)
```

Full Code:

```js
// var colors = ['purple', 'blue','teal', 'green','yellow','coral','red','gray'];
var colors = ['red', 'coral','yellow','green','teal','blue','purple','gray'];
var sizes = ['50','100','200','300','400','500','600','700','800'];

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#palette').empty();
  $.each(sizes, function(i, val){
    $('#starter').append('<div data-step="' + val + '" class="color-block"></div>')
  });
  $.each(colors, function(i, val){
    $('#starter').clone().prop('id', val).appendTo('#palettes');
    $('#' + val + ' .color-block').data('color', val);
  });
  $('#starter').remove();
  
  $('.color-block').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        step = $this.data('step'),
        colorName = $this.data('color');
    
    $this.addClass('bg-' + colorName + '-' + step);
    $this.append('bg-' + colorName + '-' + step);
    
    setTimeout(function($this){
      var colorRgb = $this.css('backgroundColor');
      $this.append('</br>' + colorRgb);
    }, 100, $this)
   
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#palettes {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.palette {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
}

.color-block {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
          transition-duration: .5s;
}

.bg-purple-50 {
  background: #efe7fe;
}

.bg-purple-100 {
  background: #c19ff9;
}

.bg-purple-200 {
  background: #a16ff6;
}

.bg-purple-300 {
  background: #823ff3;
}

.bg-purple-400 {
  background: #630ff0;
}

.bg-purple-500 {
  background: #4f0cc0;
}

.bg-purple-600 {
  background: #3b0990;
}

.bg-purple-700 {
  background: #280660;
}

.bg-purple-800 {
  background: #140330;
}

.bg-blue-50 {
  background: #e7f5fe;
}

.bg-blue-100 {
  background: #9fd6f9;
}

.bg-blue-200 {
  background: #6fc2f6;
}

.bg-blue-300 {
  background: #3fadf3;
}

.bg-blue-400 {
  background: #0f99f0;
}

.bg-blue-500 {
  background: #0c7ac0;
}

.bg-blue-600 {
  background: #095c90;
}

.bg-blue-700 {
  background: #063d60;
}

.bg-blue-800 {
  background: #031f30;
}

.bg-teal-50 {
  background: #e7fcfe;
}

.bg-teal-100 {
  background: #9ff4f9;
}

.bg-teal-200 {
  background: #6feff6;
}

.bg-teal-300 {
  background: #3fe9f3;
}

.bg-teal-400 {
  background: #0fe4f0;
}

.bg-teal-500 {
  background: #0cb6c0;
}

.bg-teal-600 {
  background: #098990;
}

.bg-teal-700 {
  background: #065b60;
}

.bg-teal-800 {
  background: #032e30;
}

.bg-green-50 {
  background: #ebf9f2;
}

.bg-green-100 {
  background: #b0e9ca;
}

.bg-green-200 {
  background: #88ddb0;
}

.bg-green-300 {
  background: #60d295;
}

.bg-green-400 {
  background: #38c77b;
}

.bg-green-500 {
  background: #2d9f62;
}

.bg-green-600 {
  background: #22774a;
}

.bg-green-700 {
  background: #175031;
}

.bg-green-800 {
  background: #0b2819;
}

.bg-yellow-50 {
  background: #fff3db;
}

.bg-yellow-100 {
  background: #ffdb8e;
}

.bg-yellow-200 {
  background: #ffcb5b;
}

.bg-yellow-300 {
  background: #ffbb28;
}

.bg-yellow-400 {
  background: #f4a700;
}

.bg-yellow-500 {
  background: #c18400;
}

.bg-yellow-600 {
  background: #8e6100;
}

.bg-yellow-700 {
  background: #5b3e00;
}

.bg-yellow-800 {
  background: #281b00;
}

.bg-coral-50 {
  background: #feede7;
}

.bg-coral-100 {
  background: #f9b69f;
}

.bg-coral-200 {
  background: #f6926f;
}

.bg-coral-300 {
  background: #f36d3f;
}

.bg-coral-400 {
  background: #f0490f;
}

.bg-coral-500 {
  background: #c03a0c;
}

.bg-coral-600 {
  background: #902c09;
}

.bg-coral-700 {
  background: #601d06;
}

.bg-coral-800 {
  background: #300f03;
}

.bg-red-50 {
  background: #fceff0;
}

.bg-red-100 {
  background: #f1aeb0;
}

.bg-red-200 {
  background: #e98385;
}

.bg-red-300 {
  background: #e1585b;
}

.bg-red-400 {
  background: #d92d30;
}

.bg-red-500 {
  background: #b32023;
}

.bg-red-600 {
  background: #88181b;
}

.bg-red-700 {
  background: #5c1112;
}

.bg-red-800 {
  background: #31090a;
}

.bg-gray-50 {
  background: #f0f3f5;
}

.bg-gray-100 {
  background: #c3ced5;
}

.bg-gray-200 {
  background: #a5b6c0;
}

.bg-gray-300 {
  background: #879dab;
}

.bg-gray-400 {
  background: #698596;
}

.bg-gray-500 {
  background: #546a78;
}

.bg-gray-600 {
  background: #3f505a;
}

.bg-gray-700 {
  background: #2a353c;
}

.bg-gray-800 {
  background: #151b1e;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="palettes">
  <div class="palette" id="starter">
  </div>
</div>
```