# CSS Typed OM -- parsing background color?

Tags: javascript, css, cssom, css-houdini

```js
const box = document.getElementById('rb');

console.log(box.computedStyleMap().get('background-color'))
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="rb" class="box red"></div>
```

Using the new CSS Typed Object Model, I'm trying to get the background color of this div. It gives me back a `CSSStyleValue` which only seems to have a `toString()` method. I was hoping it would parse the color into an RGB triplet or something else useful like it does for widths.

Is there an API for parsing colors, or has this not been specced out yet?

(I know I can parse the string by hand, that's not the question)

Comment: I don’t think there is any API to do that. Also the JS don’t have any specified format. You might get `”red”` or `rgb()` or `hex`...

Comment: One question: what's the reason you don't already know the background color? Like, if you control the project, your javascript ought to already know what color the background is.

Comment: @Akxe `getComputedStyle` returns `rgb(255, 0, 0)` whether I use "red", rgb() or hex in both Chrome and Firefox, but I'm not sure if that's per spec or a happy coincidence -- but that's really getting at the meat of this question -- there *should* be an API so that we *can* manipulate colors in a consistent way.

Comment: @frodo2975 Depends where the values come from. If I control everything, then yes, absolutely, I'd just store them as numbers in memory and wouldn't bother inspecting the DOM. There are cases when I've needed to work with DOM elements outside my control, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your premise is quite confusing...

The CSS Typed OM is meant to retrieve CSS values as they've been internally stored from parsing the **authored** values.

That makes no real sense to use it if you wish a standardized *formatted* value, since this API is really meant to circumvent the fact current APIs do only return that *formatted value*.

So if you really wish a standardized formatted value, just use `getComputedStyle` which [per specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#serialize-a-css-component-value) will serialize the <color> component according to these rules:

> - If <color> is a component of a resolved or computed value, then return the color using the `rgb()` or `rgba()` functional notation as follows:
>
>   1. If the alpha component of the color is equal to one, then return the serialization of the `rgb()` functional equivalent of the opaque color.
>   2. If the alpha component of the color is not equal to one, then return the serialization of the `rgba()` functional equivalent of the non-opaque color.

In other words, if it's opaque, it will always be `rgb()`, and if it has alpha, always `rgba()`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.test > div').forEach( elem => {
  console.log( 'formatted as', getComputedStyle(elem)['background-color'] );
} );
```

```css
.named-color { background-color: magenta; }
.currentcolor { background-color: currentColor; }
.no-alpha-hex { background-color: #FF00FF; }
.no-alpha-rgb { background-color: rgb(255,0,255); }
.no-alpha-rgb-perc { background-color: rgb(100%,0%,100%); }
.no-alpha-hsl { background-color: hsl(300deg, 100%, 50%); }
.no-alpha-rgba { background-color: rgb(255,0,255,1); }
.no-alpha-rgba-perc { background-color: rgb(100%,0%,100%,1); }
.no-alpha-hsla { background-color: hsl(300deg, 100%, 50%,1); }
.alpha-hex { background-color: #FF00FF80; }
.alpha-rgba { background-color: rgba(255,0,255,0.5); }
.alpha-rgba-perc { background-color: rgba(100%,0%,100%,0.5); }
.alpha-hsla { background-color: hsla(300deg, 100%, 50%,0.5); }

.test { color: magenta; }
.test > div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="named-color"></div>
  <div class="currentcolor"></div>
  <div class="no-alpha-hex"></div>
  <div class="no-alpha-rgb"></div>
  <div class="no-alpha-rgb-perc"></div>
  <div class="no-alpha-hsl"></div>
  <div class="no-alpha-rgba"></div>
  <div class="no-alpha-rgba-perc"></div>
  <div class="no-alpha-hsla"></div>
  
  <div class="alpha-hex"></div>
  <div class="alpha-rgba"></div>
  <div class="alpha-rgba-perc"></div>
  <div class="alpha-hsla"></div>
</div>
```

If and when CSS Typed OM will introduce the CSSColorValue, they will have to handle all these formats (and many new introduced by CSS-colors-4) separately, meaning you will actually have to write even more code to handle all possible values.

Comment: Hmm, thank you for quoting the spec. That's helpful to know it always be `rgb()` or `rgba()`. w.r.t CSSTOM though, even if it returns the values as authored, it will surely come with a bunch of `.to()` methods to convert it into the format you desire, right? That's how `CSSNumericValue` works now.

Comment: @mpen until it's been specced or even drafted, it's hard to tell what it will be. Colors are not an easy beast, and with CSS-colors-4 that will bring color-spaces into the game, it's not gonna be easier. But yeah you're right there might be a `.to()` too.

Answer (score 1):

You might could use this canvas hack from this answer to get always get a hex code:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5999319/2095953

```
var ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(64, 128, 192)';
var hexColor = ctx.strokeStyle;
```

Comment: Hex code isn't any more helpful. I'm thinking like `r`, `g`, and `b` as separate integers (0-255), but I left it a little vague because I don't want to impose any particular representation on the browser -- only that the values are numeric and mathable. Floats 0-1 would also be logical, or if the browser prefers to deal in HSL/HSV for some odd reason that'd also be acceptable. The alpha value should also be in there methinks.

Comment: I gotcha. However, if performance isn't an issue, it's pretty easy to convert from hex to numbers.

Comment: It's even easier to just parse it as is: `'rgb(64, 128, 192)'.slice(4,-1).split(', ').map(Number)`

Comment: However, you don't know what format it's going to be in. CSS supports all sorts of interesting formats, like `red`, `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)`, `#FFEEDDAA`. You don't want to have to write parsing stuff yourself that can support multiple formats. Converting to hex is one way to standardize it. I will admit it's a bit awkward though.

Comment: Yeah.... that's exactly why I'm looking for an API, and I thought CSSOM would be the saving grace. If `strokeStyle` is defined by spec to be hex though -- you're right, you deserve points for that one even though it's a horrible hack to create a canvas for that :D

Answer (score -1):

I believe the tl;dr is that it's not supported yet, but it's planned: https://github.com/w3c/css-houdini-drafts/issues/159